# Hibernate 'join' fetching weird behaviour

Tags: java, hibernate, join, fetch

I have a user and a message table. User to Message are one-to-many relationships and Message to User are many-to-one relationships. I've marked one of the many-to-one as fetch join. When I 'get' a single Message, Hibernate runs a join query, but when I fetch all the messages, Hibernate runs select queries instead of a join. What could be the reason? Following are the details:

Relationship between them:

User

```
<set name="messagesForFromUserUid" lazy="true" table="message" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
        <key>
            <column name="from_user_uid" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="repository.Message" />
    </set>
    <set name="messagesForToUserUid" lazy="true" table="message" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="to_user_uid" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="repository.Message" />
    </set>
```

Message

```
<many-to-one name="userByFromUserUid" class="repository.User" fetch="join" lazy="false">
        <column name="from_user_uid" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="userByToUserUid" class="repository.User" fetch="select" lazy="proxy">
        <column name="to_user_uid" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

When I fetch a single message object, Hibernate runs one join query as expected:

```
Message m = (Message) s.get(Message.class, 2);

Hibernate: 
select
    message0_.message_uid as message1_1_1_,
    message0_.from_user_uid as from2_1_1_,
    message0_.to_user_uid as to3_1_1_,
    message0_.message_text as message4_1_1_,
    message0_.created_dt as created5_1_1_,
    user1_.user_uid as user1_0_0_,
    user1_.user_name as user2_0_0_,
    user1_.user_password as user3_0_0_,
    user1_.email as email0_0_,
    user1_.first_name as first5_0_0_,
    user1_.last_name as last6_0_0_,
    user1_.created_dt as created7_0_0_ 
from
    hello.message message0_ 
inner join
    hello.user user1_ 
        on message0_.from_user_uid=user1_.user_uid 
where
    message0_.message_uid=?
```

But when I fetch all the messages in one go, Hibernate runs select queries instead:

```
List<Message> l = s.createQuery("from Message").list();

Hibernate: 
select
    message0_.message_uid as message1_1_,
    message0_.from_user_uid as from2_1_,
    message0_.to_user_uid as to3_1_,
    message0_.message_text as message4_1_,
    message0_.created_dt as created5_1_ 
from
    hello.message message0_
Hibernate: 
select
    user0_.user_uid as user1_0_0_,
    user0_.user_name as user2_0_0_,
    user0_.user_password as user3_0_0_,
    user0_.email as email0_0_,
    user0_.first_name as first5_0_0_,
    user0_.last_name as last6_0_0_,
    user0_.created_dt as created7_0_0_ 
from
    hello.user user0_ 
where
    user0_.user_uid=?

Hibernate: 
select
    user0_.user_uid as user1_0_0_,
    user0_.user_name as user2_0_0_,
    user0_.user_password as user3_0_0_,
    user0_.email as email0_0_,
    user0_.first_name as first5_0_0_,
    user0_.last_name as last6_0_0_,
    user0_.created_dt as created7_0_0_ 
from
    hello.user user0_ 
where
    user0_.user_uid=?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Hibernate does not always use fetch strategies defined in the mapping, for HQL or Criteria queries. They are typically used for get/load. Found a reference here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=957561

Comment: "They are typically used for get/load." <= Correction: They are *used* for load().   Also, you can solve the N+1 SELECTS problem in a different way: turn on lazy select and enable a batch size on the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this might be the reason. If you run single query which is join or subquery. It is ok, there may not be any performance difference for single query. But if you are running multiple queries(in your case multiple messages), There may raise Performance issue. I would definitely choose simple select queries instead of join/subqueries. This definitely makes sense if we consider performance. This is what Hibernate does.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. My question is about the unexpected behaviour that Hibernate shows in that second query. Why does it behave that way?

Comment: It is because of Performance. To increase performance, hibernate may be using select queries instead of join. I already given answer to your question.

Comment: Why do you think running multiple select queries is more performant than running a single join query? In fact the point of join fetch is to eliminate the 'n + 1 select' problem!

Comment: Very good question Shrini! Please check how does single select query executes and how does single join query executes(not sure but I think it uses subqueries internally).

Comment: I'm not comparing a single select against a single join. I'm comparing a bunch of selects against a single join.

Comment: ok then check multiple select query execution, if you are going to execute join query and join query has to play with multiple records(in your case messages), then there may be Performance issue for multiple records retrieve.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale - Hibernate will not use subqueries for this case. See the correct answer below.   The reason Hibernate is not using the mappings is because this is an HQL query.   If you want to force it to use a join, you can do so with the 'join fetch' syntax.